# Cannot install rvm on Cygwin

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin, rvm

I am following this tutorial at http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/  on installing rvm on cygwin.

When I run their script as shown

```
$ ./osx_or_cygwin_kick_off
```

I get this error.

```
./automation/rvm/rvm_install: line 9: /home/Owner/.rvm/scripts/rvm: 
No such file or directory
```

I tried to manually create the directory for /.rvm/scripts but it does not seem to help.

I also reinstalled ca-certifications packages and the curl packages, which apparently worked for a lot of people with the same problem, but it did not help me.

I am running Windows 7  64bit  with Cygwin 2.774

Please help!!!

Comment: please open an ticket for RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: thank you. I just submitted a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, there is no simple solution to this.

For the mean time, you can always manually reinstall prior versions of ruby if you need to.  If you need older version of ruby for amazon EMR, you can always install it using a bootstrap action.

See here: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html